# What is wrong with my itoa conversion?

Tags: c, itoa

**Background**

Im trying to determine character codes for some national diactric letters.

**Problem**

Is something is wrong with my code?

```
char a = "a"; // "a" ascii code is 97

char buffer[8];

itoa(buffer,(int)a, 10);

print(buffer); // but it prints "252" instead of "97"
```

Comment: Let me warn you, `itoa` is not standard C. Correct answer is already posted by many.

Comment: And that's why we don't like casts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The character code for `'a'` is indeed 97, but `"a"` is of type `char *`. Single quotes `'` encode characters, double quotes `"` encode string literals.

Try

```
char a = 'a';
```

Comment: It worked, code is fine, but now I have another problem with diactric. I will create another thread/question.

Answer (score 2):

```
char a = "a";
```

The problem is that `"a"` is a C string, a pointer to null-terminated array of `char`. This means that you end up assigning some part of an address rather than the ordinal value of a character.

You need to assign a `char` like this:

```
char a = 'a';
```

If you compiled with warnings enabled then the compiler would have told you about the mistake. For instance, my GCC compiler, with `-Wall` says:

```
main.c: In function 'main':
main.c:3:14: warning: initialization makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]
     char a = "a"; // "a" ascii code is 97
              ^
```

You must also never write:

```
printf(buffer);
```

If `buffer` contains any format strings, then this will lead to `printf` attempting to read parameters that you did not supply.

Instead write

```
printf("%s", buffer);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are assigning a `char*` to `char` at the line:

```
char a = "a"; // "a" ascii code is 97
```

Don't you have a compiler error or warning?

Also since you are trying to determine the character encoding you have to make sure your source file is encode correctly (UTF8, ANSI...)